build cpp code with std::backtrace raise err "undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_create_state"
I still wanna use gcc std::stacktrace, so I build my own gcc with ./configure --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes
following is my code
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/bin/g++ -std=c++23 -I/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/include/c++/13.2.0 -D_GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE -Lbacktrace  -o /tmp/t /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp

it raise err:
~/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft $ /bin/bash /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_gpp_cli.sh
/tmp/ccr6jSwc.o: In function `std::stacktrace_entry::_S_init()':
test_out_backtrace.cpp:(.text._ZNSt16stacktrace_entry7_S_initEv[_ZNSt16stacktrace_entry7_S_initEv]+0x45): undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_create_state'
/tmp/ccr6jSwc.o: In function `std::stacktrace_entry::_M_get_info(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int*) const':
test_out_backtrace.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt16stacktrace_entry11_M_get_infoEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_Pi[_ZNKSt16stacktrace_entry11_M_get_infoEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_Pi]+0x80): undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_pcinfo'
test_out_backtrace.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt16stacktrace_entry11_M_get_infoEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_Pi[_ZNKSt16stacktrace_entry11_M_get_infoEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_Pi]+0xe5): undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_syminfo'
/tmp/ccr6jSwc.o: In function `std::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<std::stacktrace_entry> >::current(std::allocator<std::stacktrace_entry> const&)':
test_out_backtrace.cpp:(.text._ZNSt16basic_stacktraceISaISt16stacktrace_entryEE7currentERKS1_[_ZNSt16basic_stacktraceISaISt16stacktrace_entryEE7currentERKS1_]+0x70): undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_simple'

I'm very confused, I have set -Lbacktrace but it still raise backtrace relative err, I guess I miss some opts when gcc build, how to fix it
I find relative question solution, but this solution guide me use boost stacktrace instead std::stacktrace, I hope use gcc std::stacktrace show backtrace meth name and line num

It either needs the build flag -std=gnu++23 or the link flag -lstdc++_libbacktrace.

I try with gcc with following configure
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist --disable-multilib --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes

and use it with
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/bin/g++ -std=gnu++23 -I/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/include/c++/13.2.0  -L/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/lib64 -lstdc++_libbacktrace -lstdc++exp -o /tmp/t /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/draft/draft/test_out_backtrace.cpp

it still raise same err
But I find more simple solution, gcc source use libbacktrace lib to impl std::backtrace, so I direclty build libbacktrace and use it, following is my code out backtrace with source file + meth name + line num with libbacktrace
#include <iostream>
#include <backtrace.h>
#include <backtrace-supported.h>

static void error_callback(void *data, const char *msg, int errnum) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << msg << ", " << errnum << std::endl;
}

static int full_callback(void *data, uintptr_t pc, const char *filename, int lineno, const char *function) {
    std::cout << "PC: " << pc << ", File: " << filename << ", Line: " << lineno << ", Function: " << function << std::endl;
    return 0; // Continue with the next frame
}

void print_backtrace() {
    struct backtrace_state *state = backtrace_create_state(nullptr, BACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_THREADS, error_callback, nullptr);
    backtrace_full(state, 0, full_callback, error_callback, nullptr);
}

int main() {
    print_backtrace();
    return 0;
}

